# Missing required options in Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm trying to create an embedded form in [Symfony2](http://symfony.com/) and I get back this error:

```
The required options 'em', 'request' are missing.
```

How can I solve this?

EDIT: 
OK, I have new information about the form. It seems the problem is when I try to include a sub-form in my initial form. It seems that it needs these two parameters but I don't know how to pass them to it.

My two entity form classes:

```html
<?php
class ContactType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder                        
            ->add('contactType')
                        
            ->add('title')
                        
            ->add('name')
                        
            ->add('givenName')
                        
            ->add('middleName')
                
            /*->add(
                'contactPhonenumbers', 
                'collection', 
                array( 'type' => new ContactPhonenumberType($options) ) 
                )
          */        
                
            ->add('contactPhonenumbers', new ContactPhonenumberType($options) )    




        ;
    }
    
   //.......
   //More functions
   //.......
}
```

```html
<?php
     
     class ContactPhonenumberType extends AbstractType
{
    
    public function __construct(array $options=null) {
        $this->options = $options;
    }
    
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {    
        $builder                                    
            ->add('position')
                                                
            ->add('number')
                                                                                
            ->add( 
                $builder->create(
                    'contact', 
                    'searchable',
                    array( 
                        'data_class'    => '....Bundle\Entity\Contact',
                        'class'         => '....Bundle:Contact',
                        'dataroute'     => '...._contact_searchable',
                        'classlistview' => new ....Bundle\Component\Listview\ContactList
                    )
                )->addViewTransformer( 
                    new NameToIdTransformer( 
                        $options[ 'em' ], 
                        $options[ 'request' ],
                        $this, 
                        array(),
                        '....Bundle:Contact'
                    ) 
                )
            )
       
            ->add( 
                $builder->create(
                    'phonenumberType', 
                    'searchable',
                    array( 
                        'data_class'    => '....Bundle\Entity\PhonenumberType',
                        'class'         => '.....Bundle:PhonenumberType',
                        'dataroute'     => '...._phonenumbertype_searchable',
                        'classlistview' => new ....\Component\Listview\PhonenumberTypeList
                    )
                )->addViewTransformer( 
                    new NameToIdTransformer( 
                        $options[ 'em' ], 
                        $options[ 'request' ],
                        $this, 
                        array(),
                        '...Bundle:PhonenumberType'
                    ) 
                )
            )
        
        ;
    }
  }
```

And my function on controller

```html
<?php

    public function newAction( Request $request )
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entity = new Contact();

        
//        $number = new ArrayCollection();
//        $number[] = new ContactPhonenumber();
//        $entity->setContactPhonenumbers( $number );
        
        $form   = $this->createCreateForm( $entity );

        return $this->render(
            '...Bundle:Contact:new.html.twig',
            array(
                'entity' => $entity,
                'form'   => $form->createView()
            )  
        );
    }
```

And the form in twig:

```html
<div class="widget-body">                               
                                {{ form_start( form, { 'attr': { 'class': 'form-horizontal', 'role': 'form', 'novalidate': 'novalidate' } } ) }}
                                {{ form_errors( form ) }}                                                                                                                        
                                {{ form_row( form.contactType ) }}

                                {{ form_row( form.title ) }}

                                {{ form_row( form.name ) }}

                                {{ form_row( form.givenName ) }}

                                {{ form_row( form.middleName ) }}

                                ------>
                                {{ form_row(form.contactPhonenumbers) }}
                                <--------
                                {{ form_row( form.salutation ) }}

                                {{ form_row( form.address ) }}

                                {{ form_row( form.superiorContact ) }}
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <hr>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        {{ form_widget( form.submit ) }}
                                        {{ form_widget( form.cancel ) }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                {{ form_row( form._token ) }}
                                {{ form_end( form, { 'render_rest': false } ) }}
                            </div>
```

Comment: Please fix your markup (indenting, remove snippet because StackOverflow can't render Twig and PHP) and try to only include relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: include a relevant snippet of code of your form and how you instantiate it

Second: it's pretty clear - without seeing the code but only the error - that you need to pass two parameters into form instantiation process

Your form should looks like

```
class YourFormType extends AbstractType
{
  //Some code here, not important for answer
  public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
  {
    //Probably some code here
    $resolver->setRequired(array(
        'em',
        'request',
    ));
  }
}
```

Your controller should looks like

```
class YourController extends Controller
{
    //Probably some actions here
    public function fooAction()
    {
        //some actions here
        $your_form = $this->createForm(new YourFormType(), $your_object)); //here you're missing options parameters
    }
}
```

How your controller should looks like in order to work

```
class YourController extends Controller
{
    //Probably some actions here
    public function fooAction()
    {
        //some actions here
        $your_form = $this->createForm(new YourFormType(), $your_object, array(
            'em' => //object, I suppose entity_manager,
            'request' => //I suppose the request object
    }
}
```

If you need to retrieve entity manager and request also (but this is only my guess reading variables name from your error)

```
class YourController extends Controller
{
    //Probably some actions here
    public function fooAction()
    {
        //some actions here
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $request = $this->get('request');
        $your_form = $this->createForm(new YourFormType(), $your_object, array(
            'em' => $em,
            'request' => $request
    }
}
```

Comment: I added this code you proposed but it return a new error: The options "em", "request" do not exist. Known options are: "action", "allow_extra_fields", "attr", ".....

Comment: @JohnKrit: is pretty clear: this is because you're passing it to "main" form but you need them into transformers. I suggest you take a look to `setDefaultOptions` of first snippet.

Comment: I tried adding "em" and "request" in the setDefaultOptions in my ContactPhonenumbers form but it still returns the same mistake.     `public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) 
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $request = $this->get('request');
        
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'CnAdmin\AddressBundle\Entity\ContactPhonenumber',
            'em' => $em,
            'request' => $request
            ));
    }`